# Calling CheckLib from SConscript file

Tags: scons

I'm attempting to check for the existence of a library from inside my `SConscript` file, as follows:

```
# Not sure if this bit is relevant:
Import('env')
env = env.Clone()

# This is what I'm trying to do:
conf = env.Configure()
if conf.CheckLib('gcrypt'):
    pass # actually something more interesting
```

...but it's not working. All I'm getting is an opaque error from `scons`, as follows:

```
scons: ***
File "/home/src/foo/bar/SConscript", line 49, in <module>
```

...where line 49 is the `conf = env.Configure()` line.

This is on Mac OS X, where I don't expect to find the library mentioned. How do I detect this in my `SConscript` file?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but I would change the Clone() line as follows: cloned_env = env.Clone(). Also, is there more error text? If so, can you show it.

Comment: Nope. That's the error text in its entirety :(

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked just fine. Maybe its a problem with how you're creating or passing  the env. Here is my sample code in case it helps:

**SConstruct**

```
env = Environment()
env.SConscript('SConscript', exports='env', duplicate=0)
```

**SConscript**

```
Import('env')

env = env.Clone()

conf = env.Configure()
if conf.CheckLib('gcrypt'):
  pass
```

And here is the result:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C library gcrypt... no
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: It turns out that you have to call `conf.Finish()` before you can call `env.Configure()` again. I'm not sure if that's documented anywhere.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, sounds like an interesting feature :)